# Making Sessions in MVC 6 Controller(with views, using Entity Framework)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I'm attempting to create a session in my UserAccountsController

```
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.Data.Entity;
using POPPELWebsite.Models;

namespace POPPELWebsite.Controllers
{
    public class UserAccountController : Controller
    {

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Register()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Register(UserAccount account)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using (OurDbContext db = new OurDbContext())
                {
                    db.userAccount.Add(account);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }

                ModelState.Clear();
                ViewBag.Message = account.FirstName + " " + account.LastName + " successfully registered.";
            }

            return View();
        }

        //Login
        public ActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(UserAccount user)
        {
            using (OurDbContext db = new OurDbContext())
            {
                var usr = db.userAccount.Single(u => u.Email == user.Email && u.Password == user.Password);
                if (usr != null)
                {
                    Session["UserID"] = usr.UserID.ToString;
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I get an error saying

> the name Session does not exist in the current context.

I need to do this part to complete a registration and login tutorial for mvc

Answer (score 3):

The `Session` property does not exist in the `Controller` class in MVC 6, instead use `HttpContext.Session` to access the session property.

Ex:

```
// get values
string strValue = HttpContext.Session.GetString("StringKey");
int intValue = HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("IntKey");
byte[] byteArrayValue = HttpContext.Session.Get("ByteArrayKey");

// set values
HttpContext.Session.Set("ByteArrayKey", byteArrayValue);
HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("IntKey", intValue);
HttpContext.Session.SetString("StringKey", strValue);
```

Comment: `HttpContext.Session["UserID"] = usr.UserID.ToString;` Now it says cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type ISession

Comment: I updated my answer to include the methods for accessing keys as they are no longer accessible using indexing.

Comment: SetInt32 and SetString are extenstion methods so you need to using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http

Answer (score 0):

**Try this.**

```cs
public ActionResult Login(User users)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using (DataContext db = new DataContext())
                {
                    var obj = db.Users.Where(u => u.Username.Equals(users.Username) && u.Password.Equals(users.Password)).FirstOrDefault();
                    if(obj !=null)
                    {
                        System.Web.HttpContext context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
                        context.Session["UserId"] = obj.UserId.ToString();
                        context.Session["Username"] = obj.Username.ToString();

                       return RedirectToAction("Dashboard");
                    }
                }
            }
            return View(users);

        }
```